# stopPropagation() of MSGestureTap event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, touch

I confused about how propagation of `MSGestureTap` event works in IE and on Windows Phone. Here is a code example:

### First

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gTLKB/2/
```

*(example tested on desktop IE11 and on Windows Phone 8 IE)*

As you can see there are two nested `div` elements. On both of them I hanged `MSGestureTap` event listeners using approach described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn433243(v=vs.85).aspx.

As you can see there is `e.stopPropagation()` for `MSGestureTap` event of inner element. So **supposed behavior** is next:

1. User clicks on inner element and see `inner click` alert message.
2. `MSGestureTap` event stop propagate and nothing happens after.

**Actual result**: `MSGestureTap` fires for outer element.

The problem will be solved if `stopPropagation()` for both `MSGestureTap` and `MSPointerDown` but in real life I have another element upper in DOM tree which has `MSPointerDown` listener which should be called, so I can't `stopPropagation()` for `MSPointerDown` event.

### Second

If you remove `e.stopPropagation()` for `MSGestureTap` event for inner element then `MSGestureTap` listener for outer element will fire twice, which for me looks very odd. Code example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gTLKB/4/
```

Order of events execution:

- inner click
- outer click
- outer click

### Third

In previous example if you will change order in which listeners are hanged on elements the order of event execution will change too. Example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gTLKB/5/
```

- outer click
- inner click
- outer click

Order of events execution in this particular case should not depend on order in which listeners have been added.

Can someone explain all that? I will be extremely appreciate for any help.

Comment: I'm seeing similar weirdness with MSGestureTap in IE11. Hope this gets answered soon. Thanks. :)